# Como cambiar una grafica de barra horizontal a vertical

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

Tengo el siguiente código, donde debo graficar unos valores de forma vertical y la grafica se me muestra horizontal. No se que moverle o agregarle para que se convierta en vertical

```
beneficio = (df['BeneficioTRV']>='Si') | (df['BeneficioFA']>='Si') | (df['BeneficioFPT']>='Si') | (df['BeneficioPDT']>='Si') | (df['DesembolsoBIE']>='Si')

filtrar_beneficio = df[beneficio]

filtro_final = filtrar_beneficio['OcupacionEconomica'].value_counts()

grafica = dict(sorted(filtro_final.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))

y = list(grafica.values())
x = list(grafica.keys())
plt.barh(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Me muestra esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y debe ser así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba invertir los ejes, quedaría así:

```
x = list(grafica.values())
y = list(grafica.keys())
```

Sino prueba en la función lambda reemplazar `x[0]` por `x[1]`

Ultima prueba, deja todo como estaba y reemplaza `plt.barh(x,y)` por `plt.bar(x,y)`, es decir hay que sacar la `h`.

Comment: si lo hago de tal manera no me lo grafica, no entiendo por que

Comment: Probá dejarlos como estaban e invertir en esta línea:
    plt.barh(y,x)

Comment: Persiste el problema,

Comment: Deja todo como estaba, donde haces la función lambda reemplaza x[0] por x[1]

Comment: Se ordena de mayor a menor, pero sigue en la misma posicion

Comment: Ultima prueba, deja todo como estaba y reemplaza plt.barh(x,y) por plt.bar(x,y), es decir hay que sacar la h.

Comment: Gracias ahi si funciono, ahora falta corregir los nombre que aparecen que se ven uno encima de otros. Muchas gracias

Comment: A las órdenes, te animás a dar la consulta por cerrada y darle con la flechita hacia arriba que es la votación de la respuesta, ayuda a crecer un poco al perfil. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: @JohnJames corregir los nombres ya es algo estético e incluso. Puedes cambiar el tamaño de la letra y el espacio que separa las barras, todo es modificable :D

Comment: @JohnJames puedes ver [este ejemplo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/statistics/barchart_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-barchart-demo-py) de la documentación de matplotlib

Comment: @Christian gracias, voy a revisar y ordenarlo